How to disable screen timeout in the i3 window manager on debian?
After a short period of inactivity (not moving the mouse and not playing media using a program like mpv (note that media played on sites like YouTube don't stop the timeout)), the screen goes dim. I am running debian, and use the i3 window manage.
I have tried the suggestion from this similar question:

The problem is not fixed after running xset s off && xset -dpms && xset s noblank. This suggestion is also found elsewhere
Running xscreensaver-command --restart informs me that no screensaver is running on display :0, which suggests that this is not the cause of the problem.


Please update the question with the following: Is the screen also turning off when using other window managers? What is the output of xset q | grep -A2 -i -e '^Screen Saver:' -e '^DPMS'? What is the output of i3 --moreversion 2>&- || i3 --version? Is your i3 window manager running any other services or programs on startup which might turn off the screen (using exec or exec_always directive in the configuration file(s))? Are you using X.Org or Wayland?

If you had another DE installed before (eg. GNOME) and still have the tools installed, you can launch the settings.
The executable's name is gnome-control-center, you can launch it with i3 launcher app (mod + d) or inside a terminal. Note that the executable's name depends on the DE you had before, so if you had KDE the name will be different.
